# Adding cast button to ActionBar using the CastCompanionLibrary

Tags: android, google-cast

I am trying to add the cast icon to the ActionBar using the CastCompanionLibrary's helper method:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    mDataCastManager.addMediaRouterButton(menu, R.id.media_route_menu_item); // This one
    return true;
}
```

I have this as my menu.xml as specified by the PDF that is included with the companion library:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/media_route_menu_item"
        android:title="@string/media_route_menu_title"
        app:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteActionProvider"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>
</menu>
```

However, nothing shows up in the ActionBar. No errors are thrown, nothing at all is visible. If I add a different menu item just to see if everything with my menu is set up correctly, that item shows up fine - it is just this cast action menu item that isn't showing up.

I have tried changing the "app" prefixes to "android", but then I get a `NullPointerException` somewhere deep in the library, and I have tried giving the menu item a different, visible icon. Nothing helps.

In AndroidStudio, the menu preview shows a menu item with the title "Play on...", so it seems like this should work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are there any available routes? I have not yet used `MediaRouteActionProvider` (it's on my short list...), so I do not know its behavior. But it may be that it only shows up if there is a detected route, and remains gone until that time.

Comment: Same issue appeared. I've done everything according the manual but Cast menu item never appears. Even in the simpliest application. But everything works in extras\google\google_play_services\samples\cast\democastplayer sample. No luck in figuring out the cause ?

Comment: Finally I've resolved my case. The culprit was my application ID. For some reason, my chromecast rejects it. I was able to show Cast icon using CastMediaControlIntent.DEFAULT_MEDIA_RECEIVER_APPLICATION_ID. Obviously, it's wrong, but my goal was a proof of concept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to register your chrome-cast as a testing devise for you to be able to detect the chromecast devise from the Android.

Check the full SDK [guide](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/developers)
Check the developer [console](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/registration) registration. You have to register you chromecast devise  in the console here, or else it is not detectable

**Update:** If nothing works, you may try to publish your app in the chromecast dev console as a last resort.

As mentioned by one of the chromecast developer try to access `http://<chromecast-ip>:9222` from browser and see if you are able to see any thing.

Comment: Please do not give the incorrect advise of "publish your app in the chromecast dev console", there is absolutely no need to publish your app in order to see that in your development devices; in fact while you are doing development, our recommendation is to keep it unpublished. If you cannot get it to work without  publishing your app, there is an issue that you need to address; "publishing" will only hide the issue.

Comment: Agreed! modified my answer.

Comment: Thanks - I may have to tweak a few things then in the developer console.My Chromecast was whitelisted and everything was working before the public release, I am now just porting everything over to use the new companion library since it handles and does so much for you. I will take a look at my settings when I can and report.

Comment: This was it - I had to put my device's serial number in my Cast developer console. After I did that everything just worked without any other changes.

Comment: I have registered my app (where should I put the App ID given?) and I registered my Chromecast and says "Ready for testing". I have exactly the same problem as you but your solution doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, these types of errors happen because proguard changes the name of the object and/or functions.

One possible solution is to add these to your progaurd configuration files:

```
-dontwarn android.support.v7.**
-keep class android.support.v7.internal.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v7.internal.** { *; }
-keep class android.support.v7.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v7.** { *; }
```

I actually had this exact error on the exact line and I didn't have my proguard configured properly for the support library.

Answer (score 1):

In my case after device registration I forgot reboot `chromecast` device

Answer (score 0):

CastCompanionLibrary and MediaRouteActionProvider are written for AppCompat ActionBar and not Sherlock ActionBar. It is strongly recommended to move your project to AppCompat since Sherlock ActionBar is deprecated so moving to AppCompat is generally a good move for your project; making that move is not difficult (see, e.g. this [article](http://www.grokkingandroid.com/migrating-actionbarsherlock-actionbarcompat/))

Comment: I am already using AppCompat ActionBar, actually, so it isn't that.

Comment: Sorry then, for some reason I thought you were using Sherlock. Now back to your issue, make sure you have registered your app on the dev console. If that is done and if your chromecast device is whitelisted (i.e. you can access http://<chromecast-up>:9222), then it should work for you (assuming your chromecast device is on and on the same wifi network)